# Puppet: Is there any way to parse XML in puppet template file

Tags: xml-parsing, puppet

I am now using json data to fill my puppet templates. I want know that is there any way to parse a xml inside puppet template.

Also there is an additional issue. I am using external facts to take data from the agent to the master. Basically what I am doing is taking my data as a string and parse it to a json inside my template. I want to parse my string into xml ( I will send data in correct format).

Regards,
Malintha

Comment: The question is not at all clear. You cannot parse things "into" JSON or XML. Please provide examples for input and what you expect your output to be.

Comment: Currently I send string as external factor from agent side and consume it in master side template. First I parse it to json and then get data from the facter.  <% require 'json'
obj=JSON.parse(@malinthas) -%>
<% obj['colors'].each do |color| -%>
<%= color['colorName'] %>
<% end -%>. Can I parse an external facter to XML likewise ?

Answer (score 0):

Puppet has no native XML support.

As for the eRuby templates - those appear to require [external libraries](http://www.ohler.com/dev/ruby_object_xml_serialization/ruby_object_xml_serialization.html) to deserialize XML.